# Count the number of 'a' and 'A' characters in a string using only recursion and pattern matching

Tags: haskell, count, counting

> Implement the `countA :: [Char] -> Int` function that counts the number of occurrences  of the characters `a` and `A` in a string.

> Hint: Whether an item is `a` or `A` or some other element can be checked by using pattern matching.

---

For example:

```
countA "Appleapplet" == 2

countA "Nietzsche" == 0
```

I'm a beginner at learning Haskell and the first thing that came to mind was to do an `if`-`then`-`else` statement but that can't be the answer, because I have to do this with pattern matching. I don't even know where to begin and I don't fully understand how pattern matching works on lists. I can't use any imported functions in this exercise.

Comment: An `if`-`then`-`else` can definitely be part of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use an `if`-`then`-`else` to check if the first character of a list is `'a'` or `'A'`, although pattern matching might be more elegant.

What you need is a recursive function with as base case the empty list (1), in that case the total number of times that `a` or `A` occurs is `0`. For the recursive case, we work with a non empty list with `x` the first character, and `xs` the (possibly empty) tail of the list. We can in that case check if the first character `x` is equal to `'a'` or `'A'` and in that case increment the result of the recursive call. We thus can implement this as:

```
countA :: String -> Int
countA [] = …  -- (1)
contaA (x:xs) = if x == 'a' || x == 'A' then … else …  -- (2)
```

where you still need to fill in the `…` parts. The ones in the second case (2) will need to make recursive calls.

Comment: Tried your answer and it works, but I'm also curious how this would look like with pattern matching. Can you tell me?

Comment: @AWheelbarrow: instead of `contaA (x:xs) = if x == 'a' || x == 'A' then … else …` you use three lines: `contaA ('a':xs) = ...`, `contaA ('A':xs) = ...` and `contaA (x:xs) = ...`. The last case will only match if the pattern matching for `('a': xs)` and `('A': xs)` fails.

Comment: And what do I need to write in the place of the ...-s? If I try ```countA ('a':xs) = countA('A':xs) + countA(xs)```, ```countA ('A':xs) = countA('a':xs) + countA(xs)```, ```countA (x:xs) = 0```, my program freezes, and doesn't print out anything.

Comment: @AWheelbarrow: you should make a recursive call on the tail `xs`, not the head. For some clauses you should add `1`, the `countA (x:xs)` should also make a recursive call.

Comment: the firs two of these clauses thus should work with recursion on the tail of the list and add one to the result of the recursion, the last one should only recurse on the tail of the list.